# How to change the 'sections' to changeable class or id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this well working code for my onepager, and need to change the target on this. How can I change 'sections' to any class or id?

I tried to add a class like ('.target') but it did not work.

```
var sections = $('section')
  , nav = $('nav')
  , nav_height = nav.outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  var cur_pos = $(this).scrollTop();

  sections.each(function() {
    var top = $(this).offset().top - nav_height,
        bottom = top + $(this).outerHeight();

    if (cur_pos >= top && cur_pos <= bottom) {
      nav.find('a').removeClass('active');
      sections.removeClass('active');

      $(this).addClass('active');
      nav.find('a[href="#'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

I need this code to work with class or id to have different targets than sections.

Other solution for me could be also: To add something like (top: -100px;) on scrolling. I have a fixed navigation bar and need the script to leave space on top.

Comment: You should be able to change $('section') to $('.target') and add class='target' to whatever you want to be affected.

Comment: var sections = $('.target') is not working?

Comment: Try posting the basic HTML that you are using also.

Comment: I think, if I could add like margin-top: -100px; to this code, I could solve my problem. Can anyone help me with it? I was trying to target an anchor with this margin already, which is maybe not necessary.